# What are the imports needed for XYGraph

Tags: java, graph, import, swt

i'm trying to create graph using XYGraph, but i discovered i'm missing a lot of jars,

i added :

```
org.csstudio.swt.xygraph
org.eclipse.draw2d
org.eclipse.core.runtime
```

but there are still more,

anyone knows which ones are missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [this](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.nebula.snippets/src/org/eclipse/nebula/snippets/visualization/ComprehensiveExample.java) example and copy the imports.